# What exactly does Button.Update do in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, vcl, tbutton

I noticed that within Delphi you can call the `Update` procedure on a `TButton` component by saying `Button.Update()`.

The `Update` procedure is also available on some other components.

What exactly does this `Update` procedure do and when would you use it?

Comment: The first port of call is to read the documentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Update` procedure is inherited from the [`TWinControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl) class which, in turn, inherits from the [`TControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl) class.

[image]

Check the documentation:

[Vcl.Controls.TControl.Update](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Update)

> Processes any pending paint messages immediately.
>
> Call Update to force the control to be repainted before any more,
>   possibly time-consuming, processing takes place. Use Update to provide
>   immediate feedback to the user that cannot wait for the Windows paint
>   message to arrive.
>
> Update does not invalidate the control, but simply forces a repaint of
>   any regions that have already been invalidated. Call Repaint instead
>   to invalidate the control as well.

[Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Update](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Update)

> Forces the control to update.
>
> Update repaints any part of the control surface that is out of date.
>   Normally, updates occur automatically, but an Update call may be
>   necessary before lengthy processing that might interfere with
>   automatic updates. Calling Update unnecessarily can increase overhead
>   and cause screen flicker.
>
> Update only repaints areas of the control the have been determined to
>   be out of date. To force immediate repainting of the entire control,
>   call the [Repaint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Repaint) method. To notify a control that it is out of date
>   (without forcing an immediate repaint), call the [Invalidate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Invalidate) method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would add my own answer here as well since I now understand what the `Update` procedure does and how it works.

---

The `Update` procedure is a method of the `TControl` class, which is the base class for all visual components that can appear on a form including the `TButton` component. The `Update` procedure is used to repaint the control and its child controls, if it has any child controls.

The `Update` procedure is called automatically by Delphi when necessary, such as when a control is first displayed or when it is resized.

However, there may be situations where you want to force a control to repaint itself immediately, rather than waiting for Delphi to do it automatically. In such cases, you can call the `Update` procedure manually on a control. For example, if you have a `TButton` component that changes its caption or color in response to some user action, you might want to call `Update` after making the change to ensure that the new appearance is immediately visible on the screen instead of waiting for the Windows Paint message to arrive and Delphi to respond on that.

---

To summarize, calling `Update` on a `TButton` in Delphi forces it to repaint itself immediately. You would use this method when you want to ensure that changes to a button’s appearance are immediately visible on the screen.